# Ubuntu suspends when I start the computer

Tags: suspend, power-management

Everytime that I start Ubuntu 20.04.1 and once I login, my computer goes to sleep(Suspend). Then only I have to press the power button and the computer wakes up and everything runs correctly.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Inspect the logs with `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks!!, The only thing I found is suddently appears a line with "systemd-logind[1118]: Suspending..." and then the system is suspended. Could be a failure in the power management?